# Convert mysql string to defined mysql variable in timing event

Tags: mysql, date, intervals, timing

I have saved timed events in a database. These events are yearly, quarterly, monthly, weekly and every day. So I added a table that stores the type of event it is.

Now I want to select **only** the events that need to be done today. So I want select the starting date of the event, add the time to it (YEAR, QUARTER, etc.) and then see if that date is todays date.

This would be the where statement:

```
WHERE (
    DATEDIFF(NOW(),
        DATE_ADD(
            IFNULL(
                timer.last_trigger,
                timer.start_date
            ), 
            INTERVAL 1 timer.period_type
         )
    )
) = 0
```

The query breaks on the point where it says:

```
INTERVAL 1 timer.period_type
```

Because that should be something like:

```
INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

So I want to convert my 'variable' `timer.period_type` with the value `'YEAR'` to the defined mysql var `YEAR`. And the same thing ofcorse if it's QUARTER, MONTH, WEEK or DAY.

Is there a way to do this, or is there a workaround? Maybe it's possible to change the column type of the `timer.period_type`? want to prevent looping trough the data with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there is workaround, you can use a `CASE` statement, for example:

```
SELECT BLA-BLA-BLA
/*MORE CODE HERE*/

WHERE (
  DATEDIFF(NOW(),
    CASE timer.period_type 
    WHEN 'YEAR' THEN 
      DATE_ADD(IFNULL(timer.last_trigger,timer.start_date), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
    WHEN 'MONTH' THEN
      DATE_ADD(IFNULL(timer.last_trigger,timer.start_date), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
    WHEN 'WEEK' THEN
      DATE_ADD(IFNULL(timer.last_trigger,timer.start_date), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
    WHEN 'DAY' THEN
      DATE_ADD(IFNULL(timer.last_trigger,timer.start_date), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    END
  )
)= 0
```

Comment: Although I like your idea, somehow the CASE system doesn't work with `INTERVAL 1 YEAR`... Any workaround for that? :-)

Comment: Sure, let`s say 1 year = 365 days or 12 months... :)

Comment: Ah, I got it. `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` **only** works within the `DATE_ADD()` function. So in every case this function needs to be repeated. I will edit your answer accordingly.